# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__source' of undefined

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Since I upgrade to the new spartacus version (1.5) I've seen this bug in the console. It's came from `SiteContextComponentService.getInjectedService`.

I have not implemented nor used yet this service. How I can fix this bug? Cause I strongly believe is the origin of other little problems in my develop environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `'CMSSiteContextComponent'` component type (flextype?), then it should come with the `context` cms component data from the backend. Please check if the response contains it.

[image: network chrome tab with the response the cms /pages endpoint]

Answer (score 0):

So the origin of the error was that in the `GET /pages` request I was not receiving the `context` attribute neither in the `LanguageComponent` nor the `CurrencyComponent`.

[image]